# std::ranges::sort is not usable as a 'constexpr' function when saving its return value in lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr, c++20, std-ranges

This function `f` can take C++20 ranges algorithm objects as an argument then use it:

```
constexpr auto f(auto algo) {
  return [=] {
    algo(std::array{1, 0});
    return true;
  }();
}
```

and it works fine with `std::ranges::sort`:

```
static_assert(f(std::ranges::sort));
```

But when I save the return value of `algo` in the lambda:

```
constexpr auto f(auto algo) {
  return [=] {
    auto it = algo(std::array{1, 0});
    return true;
  }();
}
```

[**GCC rejects and says:**](https://godbolt.org/z/zcs5j7)

```
<source>:10:16: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   10 | static_assert(f(std::ranges::sort));
      |               ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:16: error: 'constexpr auto f(auto:16) [with auto:16 = std::ranges::__sort_fn]' called in a constant expression
<source>:3:16: note: 'constexpr auto f(auto:16) [with auto:16 = std::ranges::__sort_fn]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    3 | constexpr auto f(auto algo) {
      |                ^
<source>:7:4: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'f<std::ranges::__sort_fn>::<lambda()>'
    4 |   return [=] {
      |          ~~~~~
    5 |     auto it = algo(std::array{1, 0});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 |     return true;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    7 |   }();
      |   ~^~
<source>:4:10: note: 'f<std::ranges::__sort_fn>::<lambda()>' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    4 |   return [=] {
      |          ^
```

Why this function becomes non-'`constexpr`' when I try to save `algo`'s return value?  **or it just a bug**?

**Update**: The following code will be [**accepted by GCC**](https://godbolt.org/z/Wsv1K9) so this is most likely a bug and I already filed a [**bug report**.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96575)

```
constexpr auto f(auto algo, auto... args) {
  return [=] () mutable {
    auto it = algo(args...);
    return true;
  }();
}

// those are ok
static_assert(f(std::ranges::reverse, std::array{0})); 
static_assert(f(std::ranges::fill, std::array{0}, 0));
// those are not ok
// static_assert(f(std::ranges::sort, std::array{0}));    
// static_assert(f(std::ranges::replace, std::array{0}, 0, 0)); 
// static_assert(f(std::ranges::unique, std::array{0}));
// static_assert(f(std::ranges::next_permutation, std::array{0}));
// static_assert(f(std::ranges::prev_permutation, std::array{0}));
```

Answer (score -2):

It works for me, if I declare the iterator **it** to be constexpr:

```
constexpr auto it = algo(std::array{1, 0});
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain *why*. By your logic, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/s7dTEn) should fail to compile as well, since `a` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Right. I thought maybe because int is a literal type while the type of 'it' isn't. But in fact std::array<T>::iterator **is** a literal type and the definition of std::ranges::sort is constexpr.

However, simply sorting the array without assigning its return value to a variable also compiles.

https://godbolt.org/z/3a6oe5

So I guess it's a bug.

Comment: It doesn't return `std::array::iterator`

Comment: I suspect that there is either a compiler bug or a complex rule that don't allow the function to be constexpr. Question like that usually expect an in depth explanation or confirm that this is a bug from the implementer.